# PDO Mutiple Query execute and catch error

Tags: mysql, exception, pdo, php-5.3

i need to execute three queries and find out which query is failed in PDO.

My config php

```
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password,array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, FALSE));
```

My class file

```
 class myClass
 {
     function lastbench()
     {

try {

        $q1 = "select * from user";
        $code_pre = $dbh->prepare($q1);
    $code_pre->execute();
        if(!$code_pre)
        {
           throw new Exception("no table called user");
         }

          $q2 = "select * from userprofile";
        $code_pre2 = $dbh->prepare($q2);
    $code_pre2->execute();
         if(!$code_pre2)
        {
           throw new Exception("no Profile table");
         }
      }
catch ( Exception $e)
   {
  $e->getMessage();
     }
     }



  }
```

Any idea how to get the specific block is not executing..

Comment: are you running these queries for real?

Comment: I suggest you learn about PDO before playing with classes.